# How to drag and drop multiple words in react dnd

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

How can I drag several words from a sentence by highlighting the selected words and being able to drag and drop from one text box to another using react-beautiful-dnd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved with this https://react-beautiful-dnd.netlify.app/?path=/story/multi-drag--pattern. It worked for me.